# How do I import the pytest monkeypatch plugin?

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I want to use the [pytest monkeypatch](https://pytest.org/latest/monkeypatch.html) plugin, but I can't figure out how to import it. I've tried:

- `import monkeypath`
- `import pytest.monkeypatch`
- `from pytest import monkeypatch`

Comment: `pytest`'s internals, such as the `MonkeyPatch` class, are located in a package named `_pytest`. You *can* import it, but the leading underscore is basically a polite indicator that whatever name you're importing is private and you should think carefully about using it. PEP8 explains this convention here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's not a plugin, it's a built-in [pytest fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html).

In a nutshell, that means you simply write a test with a `monkeypatch` argument, and the test will get the monkeypatch object as that argument.

The page you linked has a simple example:

```
def test_some_interaction(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("os.getcwd", lambda: "/")
```

Answer (score 11):

Just to confirm [Eric Fulmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1893155/eric-fulmer)'s comment, if you do happen to want to use MonkeyPatch from within Python for whatever reason, it worked for me like this (based on [The Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2085149/the-compiler)'s answer)

```
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch

def test_some_interaction(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("os.getcwd", lambda: "/")

test_some_interaction(MonkeyPatch())
```